# Isomorphic as sets. Do they mean bijective? (Kashiwara's Categories & Sheaves)

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

[Here's the book](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kashiwara2.pdf). On page 10 it says:

> A set is called $\mathcal{U}$-small if it is isomorphic to a set belonging to $\mathcal{U}$.

and on page 11 it says:

> A category $C$ is called a $\mathcal{U}$-category if $\text{Hom}_C(X, Y )$ is $\mathcal{U}$-small for any $X, Y ∈ \text{Ob}(C)$.

So what is meant by isomorphic here?

Comment: That cannot mean anything but bijective